# File uploading on live server failing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Picture);   
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/Content/" + Name), bytes);
```

This code works well on local server but when I try to run it on live server this gives error and file is not uploaded in content folder.

Comment: _this give error_ What error?

Comment: that is the thing which i cannot sort out.

Comment: internal server error

Comment: `500 (Internal Server Error)` almost always means your throwing an exception in the controller method. Use your browser tools (the Network tab) to inspect the response and see the error details.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you have write permission of folder where you are trying to save the image. I feel that might be only problem, otherwise `Server.MapPath(.....` should work fine.

Comment: I have give permission to that folder but after this still its not working

Comment: Have u used any try catch block? Logged exception?